# How could i know the random number generated in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, numbers

Here is my code. I am just starting to learn Python. 
I am trying to generate a random number and guess it. If the answer is 7, then my program will print "lucky". If not, then "unlucky". I try to run my simple code many times. Every time I get "unlucky". Is there anybody who knows whether the problem is in my algorithm or somewhere else. BTW, I really want to know how could I know specifically know what is the number randomly generated in python? I just wonder if the same number, that is being generated every time, is the same one or not.

```
from random import randint
z = input("What's the max number you want me to guess?")
choice = f"randint(1,{z})"
if choice == 7:
    print("lucky")
else:
    print("unlucky")
```

Comment: The random number generated is *random*. You cannot know beforehand which number will be generated. If you want to see which number is generated, you can print it out.

Comment: If you want the sequence of random numbers generated by your program to be repeatable, you can use the [`seed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.seed) function (or you can save the state with `getstate` and restore it with `setstate`, or you can create a `Random` instance and pickle and unpickle it, etc.).

Comment: Hey, Miller. Thank you so much. I just did as what you said. then I found out that the choice which is suppose to be a variable is actually a string "randint(1.10)"(I try 10 as the max number). So this code didn't realize what i want to do at the beginning. I try to make choice = randint(1,z). Visual studio told me that TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'set' and 'int'. How could i do with it?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting unlucky every time has nothing to do with randomness.

Try running your code in the debugger, or adding a `print(choice)`, to what what you're getting.

If you enter, say, `10`, then `choice` is the string `"randint(1,'10')"`. That string is never going to be equal to the number `7`.

To make this work, you need to change two things:

- Actually call `randint`, instead of making a string that looks like the source code to call it.
- Call it on a number, like `10`, not a string, like `'10'`.

So:

```
choice = randint(1, int(z))
```

---

Once you fix this, the random numbers will be random. Technically, they're created by a PRNG (pseudo random number generator), a fancy algorithm that takes a bunch of state information and spits out a sequence of numbers that *look* random, but are actually predictable from that state. But, as explained under [`seed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.seed), by default, Python seeds that generator with [`os.urrandom`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.urandom) (which, on most platforms, is another PRNG, but is itself seeded by whatever actual random data is available).

If you want the sequence to be repeatable, for testing, you can call the `seed` function manually. For example, this program:

```
from random import randint, seed
seed(42)
z = input("What's the max number you want me to guess?")
choice = randint(1, int(z))
print(choice)
```

… will give you `2` every time you ask for a random number between 1 and 10.

Comment: Soooo Helpful! My curiosity has blown up!  There are so many things interesting in Python.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check whether the same number is being guessed by random, just use `print`, to check it. Here:

```
from random import *
z = int(input("What's the max number you want me to guess?"))
choice = randint(1,z)
print("The number that I guessed:",choice)
if choice == z:
    print("I gussed it! I got lucky.")
else:
    print("I couldn't guess it, I got unlucky.")
```

Comment: I just find out that the trivial problem which is also crucial mistake is that I didn't put int in front of the z.  Thank you soooo much for giving me detailed answer.